# Firebase storage upload signed URL CORS issue

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors, google-cloud-storage

I am building an app for the web hosted on Firebase where I am trying to allow unauthenticated users to upload an image to Storage (after passing a reCAPTCHA).

To do this I have a React website and a Firebase function that validates the reCAPTCHA and then generates a signed URL for the client-side code to upload the image to the default bucket. I have deployed the Function to the cloud because there is no Storage emulator I can use for local development but my React app is being served locally.

The code below omits the usual boilerplate.

**Firebase Function Code:**

```
const id = uuidv4()
const bucket = storage.bucket("project-id.appspot.com");
const file = bucket.file(id)

const expires_at = Date.now() + 300000;

const config = {
  action: 'write',
  version: 'v2',
  expires: expires_at,
  contentType: 'application/octet-stream'
};

file.getSignedUrl(config, (err, url) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).end();
    return;
  }
  res.send(url);
});
```

This returns a URL to the client of the form: `https://storage.googleapis.com/project-id.appspot.com/db9a5cc5-6540-4f40-933f-cfdb287b15a9?GoogleAccessId=project-id%40appspot.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1594719835&Signature=<signature here>`

**Client-side Code**:

Once this is received on the client-side I try to upload the file to that URL using the PUT method:

```
// signed_url is the url returned from the first API call to the function above.
// image_file is the file data I get from using react-dropzone.

axios({
  method: 'put',
  url: signed_url,
  data: image_file,
  headers: {'Content-Type':'application/octet-stream'}
}).then(res => {

  console.log("success");
  console.log(res);

}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

This is where I get a CORS error of the form: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://storage.googleapis.com/project-id.appspot.com/db9a5cc5-6540-4f40-933f-cfdb287b15a9?GoogleAccessId=project-id%40appspot.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1594719835&Signature=<signature here>' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I used cURL to see if the CORS headers in the response were being set and they were not. I then used `gsutil cors set config.json gs://project-id.appspot.com` to set the CORS permissions on the default bucket. Here is the format of the configuration:

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["*"],
      "responseHeader": [
        "Origin",
        "Accept",
        "x-goog-resumable",
        "Content-Type",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Authorization",
        "X-Requested-With"
      ],
      "method": ["GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

I checked the service account to make sure they had the Service Account Token Creator permission and Storage Object Creator permissions set and they did.

I followed the steps at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#gcloud and I have tried every combination of content-type headers and tried v2 and v4 of getSignedURL version, as well as following any other suggestions I could find online, but to no avail.

Comment: I understand the difficulty faced when setting up CORS for a Cloud Storage bucket. For now, would it be possible to provide the CORS configuration for the respective bucket via gsutil cors get gs://[BUCKET_NAME][1](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors#troubleshooting). This will allow us to guarantee that CORS was set accordingly on the bucket in question and will help identify any further causes for concern.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, could you solve it?